# Microsoft Graph 501 Error - Get Emails

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have authenticated with Azure & OAuth to receive an access token. Now I want to read their Outlook emails through a Microsoft Graph endpoint from a native WPF desktop app using c#. However my request to get the emails, of the currently signed in user, fails with a 501 error. The delegated permissions my app has are:

- View users' email address
- Access user's data anytime
- Sign users in
- Read user mail
- Sign in and read user profile

Here is [my network trace.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9w2-YCX6qYva01ia0cxZU1kYkE/view?usp=sharing)
Now I'm getting a [404](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1qj83MVw-PZbEpxTklfS215eDQ/view?usp=sharing) too

Answer (score 0):

Based on the quest, were you authenticate the app with **external user** for the Azure AD?

If I understood correctly, the Microsoft Graph API only support for the users in the tenant.

Comment: I authenticated the app with the tenant id embedded in the url parameter in the requests to get the auth code & token, i figured wouldn't need to add the user to the tenant then? How do I add a user to the AD tenant in code?

Comment: Did you mean that you get the token without user login-in? If I understood correctly, you can try to delete the cache in the browser.